# Easiest way to read data from this website?

Tags: java, android, json

I want to make a school shceudele application (usable by only our school) that downloads data from [this website.](https://www.easistent.com/urniki/izpis/263/7326/0/0/41) The problem is that I've never done anything like that, I've never downloaded any kind of data from internet inside appplication.

I don't know where to get started and how to even begin researching this. I've seen some examples with json or xml, but they already have some kind of table in a .txt file while I only have a website here.

Could someone please explain to me in detail; what would be the best way to fetch data from this website (days, hours, subjects) insert it to .txt file/sqlite or something and then read it in my app.

I usually don't ask questions like this, I always have some code to show already but this is a whole new territory for me and I have a huge problem with even getting started.

Comment: First result on Google search "stackoverflow api": http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage

Comment: why dont you simply use WebView?  :)

Comment: @Waqas that would just simply open up this website, I want to be able to insert my own data so that I can then change then change the design and possibly save a certain scheudele in mobile device so that the user won't always need an internet connection. Or is it also possible to save a certain webview state, so that the user doesn't always need internet connection?

Comment: You have an html table filled with rows in that page. My advice is to use the API that builds the table and use it to build response format that suits you best.

Comment: You need to do some research on this. Your question is not asking anything *clear* and it's really not that welcomed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your best approach here is to show this website as is in an app that will be supply better UX for this particular table (you can download and show the data every time you want, as you can do with your PC).

Parsing this kind of data is going to be harsh, but if you have to do that, try to use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: The first phrase is not encouraging, but I was about to suggest `jsoup` myself :) So a vote up!